# How to load 3DS file using Qt3D

Tags: qt, opengl, qt3d

I successfully loaded the .OBJ model into Qt using Qt3D, but can not load the .3DS model. I just follow the tutorial from [here](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/qt3d-1.0/qt3d-penguin.html).

My environment is: Windows7, Qt5.3.1, mingw32.

Show error: `Asset importer error: Chunk is too large`

Please, give some advice.

Comment: I've seen it said, that this happens on Windows but not on Linux. You could try installing a Linux VM and running the code there, and see if it works there. I don't remember seeing a solution...

Comment: Thank you, but i want it run on Windows.

Comment: I meant testing on Linux to confirm that code and the files are valid and it indeed is the Windows-spesific issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it seems, problem is related to [Open Asset Import Library (short name: Assimp)](http://assimp.sourceforge.net/) which is included to Qt3D.

Also, note that there is big probability that you'll have no such problem on Linux.

Here is similar problem solved: http://sourceforge.net/p/assimp/discussion/817654/thread/a246ba12/

As it seems, you need to rebuild Qt3D (according to [Qt3D Installation, Windows (MinGW)](http://qt-project.org/wiki/Qt3D-Installation)) with parameter `-mno-ms-bitfields`. Try to add next line to `qt3d.pro`:

```
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -mno-ms-bitfields
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you
I re-install Qt and rebuild the Qt3d, like this:
mingw32-make -j 3 install CFLAGS='-mno-ms-bitfields'
But still not work, compiled successfully, get same error.

Comment: Sorry, I can't test it. I can recommend you to start from "clear page". Also, why haven't you done as I described? Doesn't it compiles?

Comment: I am so sorry, i did not get the point, did i miss some steps?
It compiled successfully, but still not work.